# IF statement with SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql, if-statement, triggers, insert, sql-server-2012

I am a beginner with SQL and I'm trying to create a trigger to fire with an IF statement.  Below is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Vector].[trg_insert_id]
    ON [vector].[a69]
    FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @OID int
    SELECT @OID = OBJECTID FROM INSERTED

    DECLARE @siteID float
    SELECT @siteID = MAX([SiteID]) FROM [vector].[a69]
    SELECT @siteID

    IF @OID NOT IN(select OBJECTID from vector.a69)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [vector].[a69]
              SET SiteID = @siteID + 0.00001
              WHERE OBJECTID IN (@OID)  
    END
END
```

What I'm trying to have the trigger do is, after an insert to the table, search to see if the inserted OBJECTID already exists in the table. If it does not, update SiteID field by 0.00001.

When I have the IF statement, the trigger does not work.  If I remove the IF statement, the trigger works, but it increments the SiteID field for other records with the same OBJECTID.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the trigger does not work?" Are you getting an error? Does the update in the IF statement not get executed? I would suggest to change the IF statement to say `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT OBJECTID FROM vector.a69 WHERE OBJECTID = @OID)`

Comment: No error, the update in the IF statement does not get executed.

Comment: Okay, I also noticed that your IF statement is pretty much saying if the objectID does not exist then update the SiteID where it does exist, which contradicts itself. Is this a before or after trigger?

Comment: An after trigger, I assume.  This is my first attempt at creating a trigger.  There can be duplicate objectIDs.  What I'm trying to do is when a new record is added, have the trigger search the table for the same objectID that was just added.  If it exists, do nothing.  If it does not exist, update the SiteID for the inserted record.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @OID = OBJECTID FROM INSERTED` - it's non-deterministic - you get *one* arbitrary rows, and all 24 others are **ignored** which is typically *not* what you want. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 1):

`NOT IN` can be dangerous to use.  If the subquery returns even a single `NULL` value, then the results is *never* true.  This may be the cause of your problem.  One simple fix is:

```
IF @OID NOT IN (select OBJECTID from vector.a69 where OBJECTID is not null)
. . .
```

I think a better approach is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from vector.a69 where OBJECTID = @OID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Might as well learn to use triggers correctly. First, if you ever find yourself writing something like:

```
   DECLARE @OID int
   SELECT @OID = OBJECTID FROM INSERTED
```

then your trigger is broken . It must be able to handle multiple values in the inserted or deleted pseudo-tables:

Next this part doesn't make logical sense

```
IF @OID NOT IN(select OBJECTID from vector.a69)
BEGIN
    UPDATE [vector].[a69]
          SET SiteID = @siteID + 0.00001
          WHERE OBJECTID IN (@OID)  
END
```

IF @OID doesn't exist in table vector.a60 then you can't update it.  I am partly guessing what you want to do but I think this is what you actually want in the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Vector].[trg_insert_id]
    ON [vector].[a69]
    FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        UPDATE [vector].[a69]
              SET SiteID = @siteID + 0.00001
              WHERE OBJECTID IN (SLECT OID FROM inserted)  

END
```